# Displaying image in tooltip is giving me a flickering effect when hovered over the content

Tags: javascript, css, angular, tooltip

I am using Angular here.I am trying to display an image/video inside the tooltip when hovered over the certain content. However, when I hover over the content, the image gives a flickering effect before being rendered. The transition isn't as smooth as when I put text in place of the image. How do I fix it?

I am trying to set the image src in input to the tooltip component. I have a directive which is generating the tooltip content. Code here is as:

**app.component.html**

```
<button awesomeTooltip="Hello World!"  image="https://imgplaceholder.com/420x320/ff7f7f/333333/fa-image">Hi there, I have a tooltip</button>
```

**tooltip.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { animate, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'awesome-tooltip',
  styleUrls: ['./tooltip.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './tooltip.component.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('tooltip', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate(300, style({ opacity: 1 })),
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate(300, style({ opacity: 0 })),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class AwesomeTooltipComponent {

  @Input() image=''
  @Input() text = '';
}
```

**tooltip.component.html**

```
<div @tooltip>
   <img [src]="image" width="20px" height="30px">
   <!-- Hello -->
</div>
```

**tooltip.directive.ts**

```
import { ComponentRef, Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Overlay, OverlayPositionBuilder, OverlayRef } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { ComponentPortal } from '@angular/cdk/portal';

import { AwesomeTooltipComponent } from './tooltip.component';

@Directive({ selector: '[awesomeTooltip]' })
export class AwesomeTooltipDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input('awesomeTooltip') text = '';
  @Input('image') image = '';
  private overlayRef: OverlayRef;

  constructor(private overlay: Overlay,
              private overlayPositionBuilder: OverlayPositionBuilder,
              private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const positionStrategy = this.overlayPositionBuilder
      .flexibleConnectedTo(this.elementRef)
      .withPositions([{
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'top',
        overlayX: 'center',
        overlayY: 'bottom',
        offsetY: -8,
      }]);

    this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create({ positionStrategy });
  }

  @HostListener('mouseenter')
  show() {
    const tooltipRef: ComponentRef<AwesomeTooltipComponent>
      = this.overlayRef.attach(new ComponentPortal(AwesomeTooltipComponent));
    tooltipRef.instance.text = this.text;
    tooltipRef.instance.image = this.image;
  }

  @HostListener('mouseout')
  hide() {
    this.overlayRef.detach();
  }
}
```

The stackblitz link is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e9py6n?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip%2Ftooltip.directive.ts):

I result I am looking for is:

- I should be able to send image url from the tag over which, I want to
  show the tooltip.
- The tooltip should show that image inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the overlay is setup:

- when you hover on button, overlay becomes visible
- when you move to anything other than the button, the overlay hides

The flickering you experience is due to a **never-resolving situation**:

1. When you hover on the bottom part of the button, the overlay becomes visible
2. But since the overlay starts from the middle of the button, technically you are now hovering on the overlay (and no longer over the button), so the overlay becomes hidden
3. As soon as overlay becomes hidden, you are back to *point #1* above...

This goes on and on, which is why you experience flickering effect.

for solution, add the following code to your **tooltip.component.css**, which place the overlay under the button, so that this recursive flickering doesn't happen:

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box{top:60px !important; position:absolute;}
```

UPDATE: for a bigger button, the top value can be changed to make sure that the overlay starts from under the button and that there is no overlap. [demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s1k7m2?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip%2Ftooltip.component.css)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Where exactly, should I place the code ? Should it be in CSS file?

Comment: yes, the CSS file, i wrote TS which i corrected just now

Comment: I got it. But trying that in stackblitz isn't fixing it. I tried the code in style.css file. Not working

Comment: for a thicker button like you have now, you can do `::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box{top:60px !important; position:absolute;}` and check it working on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s1k7m2?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip%2Ftooltip.component.css

Comment: Hey thanks. Ya actually it was working, I just forgot to put !important in the 'top' . Thank you

Comment: i think you mean this... check the updated stackblitz on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s1k7m2?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip%2Ftooltip.component.css

Comment: Ya actually got it. could anyways go with a parent div a position relative . Thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

For everyone searching for relative positioning of above example:

**Remove**

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box{top:60px !important; position:absolute;}
```

**!Add**

```
@import '~@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css';
```

into your styles.css. Took me forever to find out.

Source: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/building-tooltips-for-angular-3cdaac16d138

https://stackblitz.com/edit/building-tooltip

They are exactly the same, except for this minimal change :)